# Is ok to include the interface declaration of the class in the same file?

Tags: c#, coding-style

due to unit-testing we create for every class an Interface. The .Net Framework coding standards say that every class, interface, enum, etc. should be located in a different file.

As these interfaces are so closely related with the class we were thinking of creating an internal coding-standards rule to put together the class and the interface.

Have you seen this approach before? What do you think about it?

PD: Always talking about interfaces used only to mock the classes, not 'real' interfaces that can have more than one implementation.

Comment: Do you have good tools to navigate to types based on their name, not on their location? If so then your guidelines are exactly that, *your* guidelines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [do interfaces belong in files of their own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048611/do-interfaces-belong-in-files-of-their-own)

Comment: Why do you have to have an interface for every class because of unit-testing?

Comment: I would argue that you should re-consider your architecture / way of doing things. It is true that many interfaces in a code base only have one implementation, however, those interfaces and the architecture in general should still be designed in a way to allow for multiple implementations. IMO it is a bad idea to introduce interfaces *only* to be able to mock classes. Because in doing so, you skip all the positive nudges with regards to the architecture an interface based approach has to offer.

Comment: @Omribitan, for every class you would like to fake.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: of course you can always go to "Go to Declaration" VS command. Anyway, good point.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I see your point, thanks. The fact is that we are starting a project and we depend only on abstractions, not concretions (interfaces) but we currently do that just to mock thing because we have not reached the 'application extension' phase. Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow .NET coding standards and separate the interfaces into their own files. You could create a folder `Interfaces` within your project. I usually have `Concrete`, `Abstract` and `Interfaces` folders within my projects.

Developers who may be unfamiliar with your solution will have a hard time finding interfaces if they are in class files.

Comment: Nice to hear that. Thanks!